# Problem with jQuery Select Areas Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

It has been a few days I am working on this problem and I can't solve it :(. I need to use the [jQuery Select Areas Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Selecting-Multiple-Areas-of-An-Image-Select-Areas/) in my site. I can use this plugin in a simple `.php` pure PHP page outside of the Drupal area. It has `jquery.selectareas.ie8.css, jquery.selectareas.css` and also `jquery.selectareas.js` files. To insert the input image we need to use this code

```
<div class="image-decorator">
    <img alt="Image principale" id="example" src="test.jpg"/>
</div>

<script>
$("document").ready(function(){
    $('img#example').selectAreas({ //***********
        minSize: [10, 10],
        onChanged: debugQtyAreas,
        width: 800,
        areas: [
            {
                x: 10,
                y: 20,
                width: 60,
                height: 100,
            }
        ]
    });
});
var selectionExists;

    function areaToString (area) {
        return  (area.x + ':' + area.y  + ':' + area.width + ':' + area.height);
    }

    function output (text) {
        $('#output').html(text);
    }

    // Log the quantity of selections
    function debugQtyAreas (event, id, areas) {
        console.log(areas.length + " areas", arguments);
    };

    // Display areas coordinates in a div
    function displayAreas (areas) {
        var text = "";
        $.each(areas, function (id, area) {
            text += areaToString(area);
        });
        return(text);
    };
</script>
```

When I use this code in `.php` file outside of the drupal area it works well, this is the result

[image]

But when I use this code in Drupal this result is

[image]

The segment indicated by `//***********` **doesn't assign the `800px` width** and the black transparent layer doesn't cover the image. I put the `html` segment of the code in a panel content and the rest are in `js.js` file.

This is the `.js` and `.css` files

[image]

## More Information

This is Firebug result for the working one (outside Drupal)

[image]

and it is for the one that is not working (in Drupal)

[image]

As you see the width and height is `0`

Comment: What is the jQuery version of that working one?

Comment: @JimmyKo the working one version is `jquery-3.0.0.min`, But the one on Drupal is `1.10` (I am using Jquery Update module)

Comment: I wonder if it is related to jQuery version, the demo of this plugin is using jQuery 1.11. You can try if the plugin work with 1.10 first.